# Jetpack Compose and Android Room compatibility

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to set up Android Room in my Jetpack Compose project. However, when trying to add...

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3"
```

... to the app build.gradle dependencies. My build fails with the error...

```
e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationState$Builder.isIrBackend(Z)Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/codegen/state/GenerationState$Builder;
```

Any insight as to why this is? Can we use Android Room with Jetpack Compose yet?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this was a bug on the kotlin compiler which is now fixed. Not sure if they pulled the changes to the Jetpack plugin yet. Do you use the latest version?

Comment: Hi, yea I believe I'm using the latest versions. ```ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.61"
    ext.compose_version = '0.1.0-dev03'```

Comment: It has not been fixed as of today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that we're still in a state where annotation processors (for Room, Retrofit, etc.) and the experimental Kotlin compiler are not getting along. The recommended approach at the moment is to isolate the Compose stuff in a module that is independent of modules that need annotation processors.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm just testing it out atm so not vital to get it working. I'm not sure how I would go about isolating the Compose stuff in a module. Do you know of any useful material to read up on this? Thanks

Comment: @MichaelJohnston: "Do you know of any useful material to read up on this?" -- not really, if you mean documentation. As a key Compose engineer put it recently, they aren't investing much in documentation due to the APIs being in flux. However, you might want to join [JetBrains' Kotlin Slack workspace](http://slack.kotlinlang.org/?_ga=2.110923845.1590544448.1581681592-1215520910.1565297973), as they have a dedicated `#compose` channel.

Comment: Good to know. Will check out that slack channel.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not supported as kapt does not play well with Jetpack Compose. This issue is being tracked here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143232368

Answer (score 0):

It's actually working, but not without some changes.

For a new project created with AndroidStudio 2020.3.1 Canary 2:

*In build.gradle (Project):*
Downgrade **compose_version** to **1.0.0-alpha07** and **ext.kotlin_version** to **1.4.10**.

*In build.gradle (Module):*

Under composeOptions downgrade the **composeCompilerVersion** to **1.4.10**.

Under *dependencies* change "**androidx.compose.ui**:ui-tooling:$compose_version" to "**androidx.ui**:ui-tooling:$compose_version".

In Main activity - change the import for the preview, as it depends on ui-tooling.

Add room dependencies.

Should work.

*However, some newer Compose functionalities won't probably work, as they are explicitly stating, that one should use Kotlin version 1.4.20 and above.*